# C# - Microsoft Word VSTO - Update ProgressBar in Form

Tags: c#, ms-word, async-await, vsto

I am trying to update the ProgressBar for while doing some lengthy document manipulation in a Form invoked from the Ribbon button click event. But I was getting exception "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'progressBar1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

The Form works as expected when invoked from a standalone application.
Below is a mark up of a sample Form

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();           
    }

    private async void Test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar.Minimum = 0;
        progressBar.Maximum = 100;
        progressBar.Step = 1;

        var progressHandler = new Progress<int>(value =>
        {
            //throw the error: "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'progressBar' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."
            progressBar.Value = value;
        });

        var progress = progressHandler as IProgress<int>;
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i != 100; ++i)
            {
                if (progress != null)
                    progress.Report(i);
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        });
        progressBar.Value = progressBar.Maximum;
    }    
}
```

It works fine when called from a standalone app.

```
  static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

But I am getting the exception "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'progressBar1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on." when I called it from the Ribbon button click event though. See the code below.

```
   private void btnRibbon_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        var bf = new Form1();            
        bf.Show();            
    }
```

Have been playing with it for a couple days now and couldn't figure what the problem was.

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: I posted to MSDN and got  it answered - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/42688296-d214-4a2b-82cf-f5482eba6285/c-microsoft-word-vsto-update-progressbar-in-form?forum=vsto

Comment: VSTO has a long-standing issue where it does not give you a WinFormsSynchronizationContext like it should. A better solution than the MSDN forum one is to set the SynchronizationContext yourself, and then async and await will work naturally.